# Pytest does not respect DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: pytest, pytest-django

I am having trouble with setting up database configs correctly for unit-testing purposes using pytest.

My goal is to create a brand new empty test database each time I run the tests.

I have a pytest.ini file that looks like this:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = test_settings
python_files = test_*.py
python_functions = test_*
addopts = --ds=test_settings --create-db
```

My project structure is like this:

```
my_project
    app_1
    app_2
    tests
    my_project
       settings.py
    test_settings
       __init__.py
```

The test_settings/**init**.py file looks like this:

from my_project.settings import *

```
POSTGRES_USER = os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER')
POSTGRES_HOST = os.getenv('POSTGRES_HOST')
POSTGRES_PASSWORD = os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD')
POSTGRES_DB = 'test_db'
POSTGRES_PORT = os.getenv('POSTGRES_PORT')

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': POSTGRES_DB,
        'USER': POSTGRES_USER,
        'PASSWORD': POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': POSTGRES_HOST,
        'PORT': POSTGRES_PORT,
    }
}
```

And I have test cases like this:

```
import pytest
from model_bakery import baker

from rest_framework.test import APIClient

from sales.models import ServiceLocation


# TODO: вынести куда-то в общий модуль
@pytest.fixture
def api_client():
    return APIClient


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_get_service_locations(api_client):
    baker.make(ServiceLocation, _quantity=3)

    response = api_client().get('/mobile_api/v3/service_locations')

    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert len(response.json()['data']) == 3
```

When I run `pytest` command, for some reason I get assert 28 == 3 which means that python tries to connect to my original database that I use for development

Most surprisingly, I tried to delete one record from my development database table, so that the number of rows becomes 24 (instead of 25). But python seems to cache the database.
I am totally lost. Any ideas  what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Was there any resolution here? I’m running into similar issues where I can’t even find the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` value in my `pytest.ini`. Just keep getting `ImproperlyConfigured` exceptions

Comment: Grant Lindsey: do you have installed "pytest-django"?

Comment: thanx @apet installing pytest-django fixed the issue for me